# How to move a 2d object in 3d space in OpenGL

Tags: opengl, glut

Basically I create a 2d object in 3d space in OpenGL in C++. The way it's created it lies in y axis. How do I move it so it'll lie in x axis? I tried glRotatef and glTranslatef but it doesn't work. Anyone can help?

Update: I am actually making a solar system. The planets lie in x axis. But every time I try to draw the orbit for them by calling the following function, the circle always appear in y axis. I want it to be in x axis to coincide with the planet. I hope that clears things up.

```
void drawOrbit(float radius)
{
   glBegin(GL_POLYGON_BIT);

   glRotatef(90,1, 1.2, 1.0);
   for (int i=0; i<360; i++)
   {
      float degInRad = i*DEG2RAD;
      glVertex3f(radius * cos(degInRad), radius * sin(degInRad), 0.0);
      glVertex3f(cos(degInRad)*radius,sin(degInRad)*radius, 0.1);

   }

 glScalef(0.5, 0.5, 0.5);
    glTranslatef(-1.2, 1.2, 1.2);
    glRotatef(60, 1.0, 1.2, 1.0);

   glEnd();
}
```

Comment: You're going to have to be a little more specific about _how_ it doesn't work. Also, your translation code would be helpful.

Comment: Try to translate it before the glVertex3f calls.

Answer (score 1):

All scale/translate/rotate operations have to be done before glBegin, in reverse order.
spirit: you first define the camera, then you go up to the objects in their local space.

Comment: ... see the official documentation for [`glBegin`/`glEnd`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glBegin.xml) (note the small subset of allowed commands) and [`glScale`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glScale.xml) (and the rest) which *specifically* note this leads to an error state.